# Unable to locate the element when Page factory is used for webelements

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

Here i am unable to click the iframe href using the Page factory but if i try seperately without pagefactory i am unable to click the Href

DOMImage: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUIJb.png)

@FindBy(xpath="//*[@id="content"]/div/ul/li[2]/a")
WebElement iFramelabeltext;

Tried various approachs:

//a[normalize-space()='iFrame']
//a[@href='/iframe']

Need help in solving this ?

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question.

Comment: what exception u r seeing? looks u need to escape " for \"content\"

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an element using xpath=//*[@id="content"]/div/ul/li[2]/a
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'KARTHIK-PC', ip: '192.168.0.106', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to understand what is a Frame actually - it's a html code block inside entire html page code. So Selenium cannot directly access it.
You need to switch to that Frame and then perform needed actions.
How to deal with frames, see here - https://www.guru99.com/handling-iframes-selenium.html